# My image keeps disappearing after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-slider

I have an html page with menus and drop down and also an automatic image showsshow which I intend to control using the next and prev command, the code is working fine but the image on the slide keeps disappearing after few seconds.

Here is my code:

```js
let slideIndex = 0;

function showSlide(n) {
    const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    if (n >= slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 0;
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        slideIndex = slides.length - 1;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
}

function nextSlide() {
    slideIndex++;
    showSlide(slideIndex);
}

function previousSlide() {
    slideIndex--;
    showSlide(slideIndex);
}

// Initialize the first slide
showSlide(slideIndex);
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container1 {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top:10%;
  }

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Learning Roots Royal Academy</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;700&amp;display=swap'>
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css'>
    <!-- Style CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Demo CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css">
  
  </head>
  <body>
 <header class="intro">
  <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0%;"><b> LEARNING ROOTS ROYAL ACADEMY</b></h1>
  <p style="margin-top: -2%;">AFTER AGRIC, KOFARE - YOLA, ADAMAWA STATE </p>
  <p style="margin-top: -2%; color: rgb(255, 0, 0); margin-left: 30%;"><i>MOTTO: NURTURING THE FUTURE</i> </p>
  <span > <a href="#" style="float: left;  margin-left: 80%; margin-top: -3%;" >Student login</a>
    <a href="staff_login.html" style="margin-left: 90%; float: left; margin-top: -3%;" >Staff login</a>
  <div class="action">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="SCHOOL LOGO" width="20%"/>
  </div>
 
 </header>
  
 <main style="background-color: rgb(109, 0, 252); min-width: 100%;">
<!-- Start Mega Menu HTML -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark navbar-dark shadow">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar-content">
        <div class="hamburger-toggle">
          <div class="hamburger">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" style="font-size: 20px;" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li style="margin-left: 10%;" class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="font-size: 20px; " href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">Admission</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
              <li class="dropstart">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Foundation Section</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="earlylevel.html">Foundation Section</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Creche</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Pre-School 1</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Pre-School 2</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Reception 1</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Reception 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              
              <li class="dropend">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Elementary Section</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">Grade 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Grade </a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Pre-School 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Pre-School 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Reception 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Reception 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropstart">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Secondary Section</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">JSS 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">JSS 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">JSS 3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">SSS 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">SSS 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropend">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">Other Programs</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Special Computer Classes</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Swimming Lesons</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Basketball and other Games</a></li>
                  <li class="dropend">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Enterpreneurship!</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu shadow">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Cosmetics</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Curlinary</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Photography</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Entertainment</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Pasteries</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Cooking</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li style="margin-left: 10%;" class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">Academics</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                    <li class="dropstart">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Our Curriculum</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">Sciences</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Humanities</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Social Sciences</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Arts</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Library</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Academic Calender</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" href="">Library</a></a></li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" href="">facilities</a></a></li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" href="">Math Resource Centre</a></a></li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" href="">Writing Centre</a></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item">
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            
          </li>
        </ul>

        <li style="margin-left: 10%;" class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">News and Events</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
           
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" href="">LRRAThisWeek</a></a></li>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" href="">Press Release</a></a></li>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" href="">Events Calendar</a></a></li>
            
              
            <li class="dropend">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">LRRA Events</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">Summer 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Graduation Ceremony 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Science Fair 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Cultural Day 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Fruits Day 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Kindness Day 2023</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li class="dropstart">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Photo Gallery</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="summer.html">Summer 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">Graduation Ceremony 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Science Fair 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Cultural Day 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Fruits Day 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Kindness Day 2023</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li class="dropend">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Speeches</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">MD's Speech, Graduation Ceremony 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Administrator's Speech, Graduation Ceremony 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Chairman's Speech, Graduation Ceremony 2023</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Valedictorian's Speech, Graduation Ceremony 2023</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
            </li>
            
            <li class="nav-item">
              
            </li>
          </ul>


          <li style="margin-left: 10%;"  class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">About</a>
             
            <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
              <li class="dropstart">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Overview</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">History</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">Mission and Vission</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Why Study at LRRA</a></li>
                                      </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropend">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Leadership</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">Board of Trustees</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">Governing Council</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Office of the Administrator</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Administration</a></li>
                                      </ul>
              </li>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" href="">Careers</a></a></li>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" href="">Contacts</a></a></li>

              <li class="dropstart">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Institute</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">IT Institute</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">AID</a></li>
                                      </ul>
              </li>  
              
            
          </li>
        </ul>


        <li style="margin-left: 10%;" class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">Campus Life</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
           
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" href="">Campus Life</a></a></li>              
            <li class="dropend">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Student Affairs</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">Sports</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Creativity</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li class="dropstart">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Health center</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="gallery.html">Health Tips</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">First Aid Tips</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Health Centre News</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

          
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <form    class="d-flex ms-auto">
      <div   class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control border-0 mr-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-primary border-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </div>
  </form>
  </nav>
<!-- END Mega Menu HTML -->


<section>
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container1">
  
  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 8</div>
  <img src="img/BG 04.jpg" style="width:100%; ">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 10%; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><H1 style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 45px;">ADMISSION IS ONGOING</H1>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" style="font-size: x-large; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 248, 248); color: black; margin-left: -1.3%; " href="lrraeducators.html">WATCH VIDEO</a></li></li>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 8</div>
  <img src="img/BG 02.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 8</div>
  <img src="img/BG 05.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">4 / 8</div>
  <img src="img/4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">5 / 8</div>
  <img src="img/5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">6 / 8</div>
  <img src="img/6.jpg" style="width:100%; height:20%;">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">7 / 8</div>
  <img src="img/7.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">8 / 8</div>
  <img src="img/8.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <!-- <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a> -->
  </div>
  <br>
  
  <!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
     <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
       <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span>
         <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span>
    <!-- Add more dots for each slide -->
</div>

<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev" onclick="previousSlide()">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="nextSlide()">&#10095;</a>

</section>


 </main>
 <li><a class="dropdown-item" style="font-size: x-large; text-align: center; background-color: orangered; color: white;" href="img/20221122_181012.mp4">WATCH OUR MAIDEN GRADUATION CEREMONY</a></li> </div>
 <div style=" text-align: center; min-width:100%;" > <ul >

  <li><a class="dropdown-item" style="font-size: x-large; text-align: center; background-color: brown; color: black; margin-left: -1.3%; " href="lrraeducators.html">MEET THE EDUCATORS</a></li></li>


  <footer class="credit">Author: F. M. Kwende - Distributed By: <a title="Awesome web design code & scripts" href="#" target="_blank">MAFIDO</a></footer>
  
<!-- Bootstrap 5 JS -->
<script defer src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script>

<script defer> 

  document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    // Hamburger menu
    if(e.target.classList.contains('hamburger-toggle')){
      e.target.children[0].classList.toggle('active');
    }
  })   
      
</script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

That's the entire page code. I don't know if it's the positioning or it is been affected by a CSS code or any other JavaScript code that is triggering it to disappear. Thanks for your support.

Comment: hi, could you shorten your code down into a [mre]? - that's an example where the error appears in a short code example, rather than a full script that can take a while to debug

Comment: You were using `showSlide(slideIndex);` twice in your codes and I removed one.

Comment: In your `img` sources please remove gaps `<img src="img/BG 02.jpg" style="width:100%">`. It should be: `img/BG02.jpg` and also make the same change on the actual image file names.

Comment: It is because of the `fade` animation. If you can remove those classes from the images then the images remain.

Comment: Thank you very much Md. Rakibul Islam. that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Bootstrap CSS there's:

```css
.fade:not(.show) {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove space from all BG 01.jpg, BG 02.jpg, BG 03.jpg, BG 04.jpg, BG 05.jpg images. beacase html unable to find images with space on it